# How do I pull integer from method?

Tags: java, loops, methods

I have to use the method `public static int getMenuOption`, and I am having trouble getting it to return an integer.

It has to loop the way I have it, which is repeating loop if selection is correct or if wrong 3 times in a row you will exit.

I am having trouble understanding how to pull the intValue out of the loop?

```
public static int getMenuOption() {
    Scanner theScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        int intValue = 1;
        while (intValue > 0 && intValue < 6) {
            System.out.println("Menu");
            System.out.println("1. Add");
            System.out.println("2. Subtract");
            System.out.println("3. Multiply");
            System.out.println("4. Divide");
            System.out.println("5. Generate a random number");
            System.out.println("6. Quit\n");
            System.out.print("What would you like to do? ");
            intValue = theScanner.nextInt();
            if (intValue > 6 || intValue < 1) {
                System.out.println("I'm sorry, " + intValue +
                    " wasn't one of the options");
            }

        }
    }

    return intValue;
}
```

Comment: Did you try using the `return` statement?

Comment: What is it returning and what are you expecting it to return?

Comment: it needs to return that number for instance 1 for add so i can call another method to add

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your while condition is wrong.

Should be :

`while(intValue <=0 || intValue >6)`

since you want to stay in the loop until you get a valid input (between 1 and 6).

In addition, it's unclear what the outer for loop is for. You should probably remove it, since after the while loop finds a valid input, the method should return.

```
public static int getMenuOption() {
    Scanner theScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int intValue = 1;
    while (intValue <= 0 || intValue > 6) {
        System.out.println("Menu");
        System.out.println("1. Add");
        System.out.println("2. Subtract");
        System.out.println("3. Multiply");
        System.out.println("4. Divide");
        System.out.println("5. Generate a random number");
        System.out.println("6. Quit\n");
        System.out.print("What would you like to do? ");
        intValue = theScanner.nextInt();
        if (intValue > 6 || intValue < 1) {
            System.out.println("I'm sorry, " + intValue +
                " wasn't one of the options");
        }

    }

    return intValue;
}
```

Comment: I have to have make it so if you choose a correct option it keeps looping until you exit. It also needs to force exit if you make 3 incorrect choices in a row. Your condition make it loop ip outside of, which is not what i want. I want the for loop for be applied if it is outside of 0-6

Comment: @KipBodey Don't you want to return the correct option chosen to the caller of this method? If you keep looping when a correct option is entered, you will never pass that correct option to the caller.

Comment: ahhhhhhh so my loop for doing it correctly needs to be outside of this at the end of the program. OK. that solves that, but now how do i get the intValue as the selection when i run this method?

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is wrong.

Make it : 
`while(intValue <= 0 || intValue > 6)`

Also declare intValue outside of the for loop like so:

```
Scanner theScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int intValue;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    intValue = 1;
```

After doing this you should be fine.

EDIT:

```
public static int getMenuOption() {
    Scanner theScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int intValue = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { //Useless for loop.
        intValue = 1; //reset var each time
        while (intValue <= 0 || intValue > 6) {
            System.out.println("Menu");
            System.out.println("1. Add");
            System.out.println("2. Subtract");
            System.out.println("3. Multiply");
            System.out.println("4. Divide");
            System.out.println("5. Generate a random number");
            System.out.println("6. Quit\n");
            System.out.print("What would you like to do? ");
            intValue = theScanner.nextInt();
            if (intValue > 6 || intValue < 1) {
                System.out.println("I'm sorry, " + intValue +
                    " wasn't one of the options");
            } else {
                return intValue;
            }

        }
    }

    return intValue;
}
```

I believe this is the desired code you want:

EDIT:

```
public static int getMenuOption() {
    Scanner theScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    int intValue = 1;
        while (intValue <= 0 || intValue > 6) {
            System.out.println("Menu");
            System.out.println("1. Add");
            System.out.println("2. Subtract");
            System.out.println("3. Multiply");
            System.out.println("4. Divide");
            System.out.println("5. Generate a random number");
            System.out.println("6. Quit\n");
            System.out.print("What would you like to do? ");
            intValue = theScanner.nextInt();
            if (intValue > 6 || intValue < 1) {
                System.out.println("I'm sorry, " + intValue +
                    " wasn't one of the options");
                count++;
            } else if (count == 3 || intValue <= 6 && intValue >= 1) {
                return intValue;
            }

    return intValue;
}
```

Comment: i cant make declare intValue = 1 outside of loop since it is defined inside the loop, it says cant be resolved to a variable.

Comment: @KipBodey See the edit. Thats the way I meant for you to declare the variable.

Comment: okay that fixed. i am still not sure how when the correct option is chosen i get it to stop repeating and pull the integer

Comment: @KipBodey See edit. Although I am still not sure why you need the outside for loop, as removing it will make sure that unless the user chooses a valid input he will never exit the while loop. Thus giving you the desired effect.

Comment: @KipBodey I am not sure why you insist on having the for loop, so i provided a code example that doesn't include it.

Comment: the entire program has to exit if 3 wrong choices in a row are entered, and the entire program has to repeat if all goes well

Comment: @KipBodey So add a System.exit(0) after the for loop. Did I solve your question?